# Conditional highlight row when there are matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-formatting, multiple-matches

In Excel, I want to add a gradient highlight by row when the text changes in a given cell, with conditional formatting. I have a list of ~1k account names, a lot of which are the same, and I have them all sorted alphabetically. I'd like to set Conditional Formatting to group each account name together by the entire row. For example: cell A1=`McDonalds` A2=`McDonalds` A3=`Wal-Mart` A4=`Wal-Mart`.

I'd like the colors to group each account together so `McDonalds` would be blue and `Wal-Mart` would be green.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a helper column, say E seeded with `1` in row1, and `=IF(A1=A2,E1,E1+1)` in E2 and copied down to suit. Then formulae of the kind below should suit for conditional formatting:

[image: SO15396273 example]